# Multi settings in Django

Tags: python, django

I've created in my project settings folder, where I handle development and production. I've added an extra application in production file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'google_analytics']
```

Now I need to add `re_path('djga/', include('google_analytics.urls'))` to main urls.py. How i can add it when settings are in production mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check from DEBUG = True/ Flase from settings varible. make condition in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += re_path('djga/', include('google_analytics.urls'))
```